# finding the measurement of object using open-CV using python

Tags: python, opencv

I need a guidance or help from here. I tried to measure the size of object(inch) using open-cv. [the link for that reference](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/)

The problem im facing is , when you run a code

```
$ python object_size.py --image images/example_01.png --width 0.955
```

you need to define width size. without defining the width how to get the measurement. can anyone help me?

edit1:

[image]

assume books inside the image as object. i dont have any clue regarding the reference size.

is there any way to estimate?

thanks in advance.

Comment: i have a same problem like this.

Comment: You can't. How could you get the size of an object on a picture if you do not provide the size of the reference object? Did you get that --width stands for the reference object and not the width of the image ?

Comment: is there any other possible way.? in my problem there is no reference size ..

Comment: The other possible way is to measure the working distance (much more difficult than measuring a reference object and placing it in the scene) and do a bunch of other math. If all you have is a photo of objects of unknown size taken with unknown hardware in an unknown setup... you're out of luck.

Comment: @DanMašek assume the book on above pic as my targeted object. what are all things to be calculated to estimate the size of the book?

Comment: Which book i don't see any book. Assume that 'Iron Chic' album is the targeted object. Then you need to choose between one of the three others objects and provide height or width to be able to guess the targeted object size. The reference object is used the same way you use the map scale to compute distance between two points on a map.

Answer (score 0):

The example assumes that there is a reference object of a known size as the left most object. It uses the size of the object to get a measure of how many pixels makes an inch. If you don't have such a reference object, but still want a measure in inches you need to supply the pixelsPerMetric variable directly. 
This can be done by changing the lines 17 and 18 to

```
ap.add_argument("-m", "--metric", type=float, required=True,
help="how many pixel are in one inch / cm. Supply 1 if you want the object size in units of pixel")
```

Now you still need to set the pixelsPerMetric by changing line 97 to

```
pixelsPerMetric = args["metric"]
```

With that you should be able to call

```
python object_size.py --image images/example_01.png --metric 1.0
```

to get the answers in units of pixel.
I haven't tested the code in detail, and you can surely clean up the code a bit, since you don't have a reference object anymore, but I'm confident it will give you good answers.